# Create an object that contains an array of objects with a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I would like to create on JavaScript an object of one array (line_items_object) that contains objects with a for loop  like this structure:

```
var data = {
    line_items_object: [
    {
       id: 8111696
    },
    {
       id: 8111688
    }
    ]
};
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Where does the value of `id` come from in this loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will create an array of 100 objects with `id` values from 1 to 100. If `id` needs to be calculated or pulled from somewhere, let me know and I'll update the answer.

```
var data = { line_items_object: [] };
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) data.line_items_object.push({id: i});
```

Comment: Oh, that great. I have it working well now as you recomended:

Comment: var data = { line_items_object: [] };
    for (var i = line_items.length-1; i >= 0; i--) data.line_items_object.push({id: line_items[i]['id']});
    console.log(data);

Comment: @PetarKirilovGeorgiev I'm glad I could help. If you liked my answer, please accept it by clicking the checkmark to the left of it.